# How do I hide files In VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

In Ubuntu, filenames starting with `.` are hidden, but whenever I open any folder in VSCode those hidden files are visible in the Explorer Side Bar. I don't want VSCode to show the files which are normally hidden in Linux, i.e. where the file name starts with `.`.

Can someone tell me how to hide files in VSCode's Explorer where the name starts with `.`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In VSCode:

- Go to **File > Preferneces > Settings**
- Expand **Text Editor > Files**
- Click **Add pattern** below **Files:exclude**

Answer (score 0):

**VSCode settings**

You can exclude files from showing in the Explorer side-bar using VSCode settings. Open **File** > **Preferences** > **Settings**, and then choose whether to edit the **User** settings or the **Workspace** settings.

> The **User** settings will be held in a `settings.json` file in your home directory and will apply to any use of VSCode on that machine; the **Workspace** settings will be held in the `.vscode/settings.json` file under the root path of your project and only apply to the current workspace.
>
> In the example given in the OP (hiding files that are usually hidden by the OS) you probably want to configure the **User** settings.

In the search bar at the top of the **Settings** you can enter `files:exclude` or expand **Text Editor** > **Files** and look for the **Files: Exclude** section.

You will need to click **Add Pattern** to add a custom exclusion to the list of files hidden in the Explorer.

---

**Excluding files prefixed with a dot:**

File exclusions use glob patterns similar to those used in `.gitignore` files. To exclude files starting with `.` you will need this pattern:

```
**/.*
```

The `settings.json` file (see above) should now have something like this in it:

```
{
    "files.exclude": {
        "**/.*": true
    }
}
```

---

**See also:**

- https://vscode-docs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/customization/userandworkspace/
- https://vscode-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/editor/codebasics/#explorer

Answer (score -1):

- Add what you want to be hidden in a .gitignore file local to your project.
- In VSCode settings, look for: "Explorer: Exclude Git Ignore".
- Tick the box.

In this way, you minimize the settings specific to your current IDE, and rely on what is specified in your project.

Comment: I think this answer would exclude files from being tracked by git and then hide those. I'm not sure that the OP needed the files to be excluded from git.

Comment: @CharlieJoynt - I just proposed an alternative approach. The fact is that usually files which are not in the VCS (e.g. git) are temporary files, that do not need to be opened in the IDE. But, of course, it is possible that some files need to be in the VCS without the need to be displayed, and in this case my approach does not work.